# can't calculate document.body.pageYOffset when using overflow-x: hidden in my css

Tags: javascript, css, performance

i can't calculate the document.page.Yoffset when i use overflow-x:hidden property in my css
is there any way to do that

```
   if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50)
      setIsScrolled(true)
    else 
      setIsScrolled(false)



html, body {width: auto!important; overflow-x: hidden!important}
```

Comment: The code you show does not have pageXOffset in it. Could you edit it to show that and also clarify what you mean by you can’t calculate it?

Comment: thank you @AHaworth i've already tackled the problem on another way